# Using wordpress, how to pass a variable using permalink

Tags: php, wordpress

Here's the scenario:

A visitor to my site lands on restricted content. I provide a link to the membership options/signup page. Upon completion of signup, I want to redirect the user back to the page they were viewing.

The membership software I'm using (s2member) provides an success=(url) option, so I really just need to send the permalink of the page they were viewing to the signup page.

The restricted content uses a template file, in which I include a signup link (if they do not currently meet membership requirements). I'm trying to use the wpfunction: add_query_arg.

So, I have:

```
<a href="<?php echo add_query_arg( '$prev_page', get_permalink(), get_permalink( 67847 ) ); ?>">Sign Up</a>
```

And on the page this links to I see

```
http:///www.mysite.com/member-sign-up/?$prev_page=http://the-correct-permalink-pf-previous-page/
```

The problem is, on the memebership page, when I

```
var_dump( $prev_page );
```

it returns

```
null
```

Is this the correct method for sending a variable using a link?

Comment: Did you try `$_GET['$prevPage']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are not interpolated inside single quotes. Single quoted strings will display things almost completely *as is.*  Change it to double quotes if you want the actual variable value to be used:

```
<a href="<?php echo add_query_arg( "$prev_page", get_permalink(), 
get_permalink( 67847 ) ); ?>">Sign Up</a>
```

And now, you can access the query parameter in your membership page, like so:

```
$var = $_GET['foo']; // where 'foo' == $prev_page
echo $var;
```

However, if you're actually trying to use the literal string `$prev_page` as your query parameter, you can simply do the following in your membership page:

```
$_GET['$prev_page']; // note the single-quotes
```